# Storing unicode strings to SQL Server via ActiveRecord

Tags: sql-server, orm, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I am using Castle ActiveRecord as my ORM. When I try to store unicode strings, I get question marks instead.

Saving unicode strings worked perfectly when I was using mysql, but when I recently switch to SQL Server it broke. How should I go about fixing this?

Comment: Gotta ask the obvious first:  What SQL Server data types are you using  -- varchar or nvarchar; text or ntext; char or nchar?

Comment: Indeed, asking the obvious is a good place to start. I changed it from varchar to nvarchar and that did the trick. If you post this as an answer I'll accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're most likely using the incorrect SQL Server data type.  `varchar` is meant for a plain-old character while `nvarchar` is meant for Unicode characters.  The same applies for `char` & `nchar` and `text` and `ntext`.

[MSDN for SQL Server data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187752(SQL.90).aspx)
[MSDN for SQL Server Unicode data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191200(SQL.90).aspx)